# Why is UriInfo.getPathParameters() a MultivaluedMap?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, cxf, java-ee-7

The `javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo` class defines [`getPathParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathParameters--) to return a `MultivaluedMap<String,String>`, and the javadoc of the interface reads:

> Get the values of any embedded URI template parameters.

The "embedded URI template parameters" this is referring to are those defined in [`javax.ws.rs .Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html), where the `@Path.value()` represents a URI template that contains curly-brace-delimited parameter names, specifying an optional regex pattern to match segments in a URI, or *"a default value of [^/]+"* is used if no regex is provided.

The URI template is compiled into a regex for the purpose of matching against request URIs.

The "path parameters" that `javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo.getPathParameters()` is referring to are constructed during the matching operation between a URI template regex and a request URI. If a match is found, then each of the named groups in the URI template's regex (defined by the curly-brace-delimited parameter names) is dereferenced, and the values are stored in a map.

And so, we come to the map: a `MultivaluedMap<String,String>`.

From my understanding, and having read the reference implementation of this logic in [org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.URITemplate](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/main/rt/frontend/jaxrs/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/model/URITemplate.java#L233-L234), how is it possible that a parameter name could have multiple values?

The only way I can see that this would be possible is if a curly-brace-delimited parameter name is repeated in a `@Path.value()` -- i.e. something like `@Path("{foo}/bar/{foo}")`.

- Does anyone know where the spec on this subject is specified?
- Is there any other way that a curly-brace-delimited parameter name could have multiple values for a single request URI?

Thank you for your help!